# Ionic App not working correctly on Android devices

Tags: json, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-http

Currently Im working in a simple APP in Ionic that retrieves data from a JSON file and  displays it in the screen. When i run the app in ionic serve/lab the app works perfectly, the problem comes when i try to emulate it or running it on an actual phone.

[Not working on the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sABld.png)

[Working on Ionic Lab/serve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gkBN.png)

The problem i think might be related to No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' or Compatibility with CORS, but i dont know what to do to fix this so i would appreciate your knowledge in this matter.

This is my code for the .ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

export class Page4Page {

  datalamp: Array<any> = [];
  datosarr: Array<any> = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private http: Http) {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.getdata();
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad Page4Page');
  }

  getdata() {
this.http.get('http://caidalibre.000webhostapp.com/data3.json')
  .map((res) => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.datalamp = data;
    console.log(this.datalamp)
    this.getlastdata();
  })
  }
  getlastdata() {

    this.datosarr.length = 0;
    console.log(this.datosarr)
    let lastdata = this.datalamp.slice(-1)[0]
    let lasttemp = JSON.parse(lastdata.temperatura);
    let lasthum = JSON.parse(lastdata.humedad_relativa);
    let lastintesidad = JSON.parse(lastdata.intensidad_luminosa);
    let lastbateria = JSON.parse(lastdata.bateria);
    let lastvoltaje = JSON.parse(lastdata.voltaje_panel);
    this.datosarr.push(lasttemp, lasthum, lastintesidad, lastbateria, lastvoltaje)
    console.log(this.datosarr)

  }
}
```

and for the HTML file:

`<ion-content padding>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let dat of datosarr">
        <p>{{datosarr}}</p>
    </ion-item>
</ion-content>`

Comment: Does it show any error ?

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast answer, No the console doesn't show any error while building the apk nor when im emulating it.

Comment: The screen just keep in blank ?

Comment: Yes like i mentioned in the main post when i emulate the app or run it on an Android device the screen goes blank, what i think is that there are no data to show in the screen. But if you see the other image i added it shows that works.

Comment: Are you test it with chrome dev tools ?

Comment: Yes, with chrome://inspect/#devices, the error is in fact No 'Acess-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present in the requested resource.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of it ?

Comment: Here it is [Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LjAZFcHXUgMxXx6EmVwgZYuYemiP_JVp/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you show me the config.xml

Comment: [config.xml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lK4c47stekzchRWn48Ubcybo15YecPPn/view?usp=sharing) There you go and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this in you `config.xml`

```
<allow-navigation href="http://ionic.local/*" />
```

**EDIT:**
Try adding this:

```
<allow-intent href="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
```

Remember to remove the platform and add it again.

Comment: Sadly it didn't work i keep getting the same error.
[Image1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oXnSCa0koVG54fRC0NDgaBjqLovTW2rK/view?usp=sharing)
[Image2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tX0vlgZaCesAEyoXDBOMMSJ1N6XrSgIw/view?usp=sharing)
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tested it in a real device ?

Comment: Yes, just now i tested it in my phone and doesn't work.

Comment: How are you running in the emulator ? I mean what command do you run

Comment: Unfortunately that didnt work either, thanks a lot for your help and time.

Comment: That issue is so weird also check this issue in gtihub https://github.com/crosswalk-project/DEPRECATED-crosswalk-apk-generator/issues/31 :')

Comment: In the end i switched to the Native Http Ionic plugin and re-made my code from scratch and it's working now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Which Native Http Ionic plugin ?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, the plugin i was talking about is this [one](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/) by the results of my app this plugin bypasses the CORS and ultimately the error i was having in Android.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem

solved by change the `http`

angular/http only for browser

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
```

use ionic-native for app

```
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';
```

more detail can read this page

[swich httpclient for ionic](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-native-http-instead-of-angulars-http/101326/5)